# What's the best way of getting Id from Url with asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Jquery and Asp.Net MVC.
i am trying to pass an ID parameter

from an ActionLink on a page to jQuery function. 
This Id is then passed to a controller that returns a resultset that is rendered in a modal dialog box.

what is the best way of capturing the Id parameter from the ActionLink in the Jquery Function?
Note there are several action links with different Ids assigned to them.

this is my action link below:

`<%=Html.ActionLink("View", "GetDetailsById", new { id = x.ProductId }, new { @class = "view",@productId= x.ProductId })%>`

this below is my jquery function.

```
       $(function () {
             var _id;


             $(".view").click(function () {
                 // Get the ID value of this button.

                 _id = $(this).attr('productId');                    

                 // Initialize the dialog and call the next function
                 // to get the data.                  
                 $("#dialog-message").dialog('open');

                return false;
             });
```

Note i got this to work by adding a custom attribute to actionlink -@productId. I then grab the value using jquery like this:

`$(".view").click(function () {
                     // Get the ID value of this button.`

```
                 _id = $(this).attr('productId');
```

This Id is passed to a jquery function that calls a method in the controller.

Is this a good way of getting the Id, or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

regards

Kojo

Comment: Curious but It looks like you are creating an action link but not actually using the link itself. But instead on click returning false and doing something else.  Am I correct?

Comment: i'm decorating the action link with css class and an Id. i didn't show all the code,  but i'm opening up a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the productId to the Id of the html element generated, by specifying an `id` in the html attributes parameter:

```
new { @class = "view", id = x.ProductId }
```

Then, instead of using a `productId` attribute, you could grab the `id` of the generated `<a>` tag in the same way, that is use `$(this).attr("id")`.

I would recommend this over using `productId` since `id` is valid HTML.

So, your code would end up looking like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("View", "GetDetailsById", new { id = x.ProductId }, new { @class = "view", id = x.ProductId })%>
```

which would generate an `<a>` with id of `productId`.  Then your jQuery would look like this:

```
       $(function () {
         var _id;


         $(".view").click(function () {
             // Get the ID value of this button.

             _id = $(this).attr('id');                    

             // Initialize the dialog and call the next function
             // to get the data.                  
             $("#dialog-message").dialog('open');

            return false;
         });
```

Comment: ..I used $(this).attr('id') but it return undefined , any idea plz? I just want to get id value in above actionlink on jquery click event

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the id to the view model then insert the value in a javascript variable manually

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var id = '<% ViewData["theid"] %>';
</script>
```

This is the same technique stackoverflow uses in their code. Go ahead and look at their html and you will see.

Comment: this is a useful technique and would work. THe only reason why i didn't accept it is because i have a List<Product> collection of data that is displayed in a table on the page. So i can't assign the individual Ids to <% ViewData["theid"] %> before displaying it on the page.